# What type of clamp is this?

Tags: tool-identification, clamps

This is a long (almost 6' / 2m) clamp. Its similar in function to a US pipe clamp but the main body is a wood block, with notches cut or drilled.

In the UK I've seen the term "sash clamp" used, but those that I saw had entirely metal bodies, and I've never heard that term used in the US.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a sash clamp to me. I don't think the material changes the name in this case, as the action is the same. The idea is a clamp that is intended to stay on for a long time for glue ups or dry fitting. Indeed, Irwin (and, I'm sure, others) makes the hardware so you can make your own by supplying the wood.

Comment: Yeah I don't know that anyone actually calls the final assembled item a sash clamp, but that is essentially what you build so you end up with a sash clamp/sash cramp even if not referred to as one. The parts you buy are called the *clamp heads*, and they are still widely made and sold in the UK. The modern ones are usually a different style, requiring drilled holes rather than the notches of this type, but they're the same basic thing.

Comment: Amazon in Canada also sells the heads, and "sash clamps" works as search terms. So, yeah. No one I know uses the term very often, but the brands still use the term.

Comment: I love it when the world is small, just posted in the last few days is this video by James Wright, [What is a Sash Clamp and Where to Get Them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NDUwRuG30M4)

Answer (score 2):

Grizzly [sells](https://www.grizzly.com/products/Grizzly-24-Sash-Clamp/T31685) a similar clamp and calls it a *sash clamp*:

[image: Grizzly sash clamp]

The same term turns up several similar models at Amazon and other retailers.

Yours is obviously not a *pipe clamp* as there's no actual pipe involved, but pipe clamps are also effectively the same thing: a head with a screw at one end, and a moveable foot that a slides along a pipe or bar.

Your clamp might also be described as a *bar clamp*, but I've seen people also use that term for F-clamps and Bessey-style parallel jaw clamps, both of which have the screw on the movable part instead of the fixed part.

Comment: That's cool, I wasn't aware that term was used in the US - but that looks essentially identical to the (fairly old) metal sash clamps I'd seen in the UK. In that case I guess the example in the question is just a more traditional / older design of basically the same thing.

Comment: I think "bar clamp" is a more generic term than "sash clamp" - I've got a rather useful trigger action bar clamp (so called by the manufacturer) that can also be used as a spreader